# blogdown::new_site() bash not found on win7

Tags: r, blogdown

summary: bash not found on win7 (git bash is available)

```
blogdown::new_site(theme = "yihui/hugo-xmin")
```

Congratulations! Your new Hugo site is created in C:\Users\John\repos\openemr-blog3.

Just a few more steps and you're ready to go:

1. Download a theme into the same-named folder.
   Choose a theme from https://themes.gohugo.io/, or
   create your own with the "hugo new theme " command.
2. Perhaps you want to add some content. You can add single files
   with "hugo new \.".
3. Start the built-in live server via "hugo server".

Visit https://gohugo.io/ for quickstart guide and full documentation.
trying URL 'https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin/archive/master.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 78899 bytes (77 KB)
downloaded 77 KB

Rendering content/_index.Rmarkdown
running: bash  -c "cd ../..;
find . -not -path '*/exampleSite/*' ( -name '*.html' -o -name '*.css' ) | xargs wc -l"

Quitting from lines 14-16 (_index.Rmarkdown) 
Error in system2(cmd, code, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE, env = options$engine.env) : 
  '"bash"' not found
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> 
Execution halted
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/Rscript" "C:/Users/John/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/blogdown/scripts/render_page.R" "_index.Rmarkdown" "C:/Users/John/repos/openemr-blog3/content"' had status 1Error in render_page(f) : Failed to render '_index.Rmarkdown'
[1] TRUE
/usr/bin/sed: can't read : No such file or directory
Warning message:
running command 'sed -i '' -e '1,6d' -e '34,38d' ../README.md' had status 2

```
devtools::session_info()
```

Session info ------------------------------------------

setting  value
 version  R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio (1.0.153)
 language (EN)
 collate  English_United States.1252
 tz       America/New_York
 date     2017-09-15

Packages -------------------------------------------

package    * version date       source
 backports    1.1.0   2017-05-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 base       * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local
 blogdown   * 0.1.4   2017-09-15 Github (rstudio/blogdown@ec651e1)
bookdown     0.5     2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 compiler     3.4.1   2017-06-30 local
 datasets   * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local
 devtools     1.13.3  2017-08-02 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 digest       0.6.12  2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 evaluate     0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 graphics   * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local
 grDevices  * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local
 htmltools    0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 knitr        1.17    2017-08-10 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 magrittr     1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 memoise      1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 methods    * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local
 Rcpp         0.12.12 2017-07-15 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 rmarkdown    1.6     2017-06-15 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 rprojroot    1.2     2017-01-16 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 rstudioapi   0.7     2017-09-07 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 stats      * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local
 stringi      1.1.5   2017-04-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 stringr      1.2.0   2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 tools        3.4.1   2017-06-30 local
 utils      * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local
 withr        2.0.0   2017-08-10 Github (jimhester/withr@190d293)
 yaml         2.1.14  2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.4.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the example site provided by this theme. Specifically, the bash code chunk in [content/_index.Rmarkdown](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin/blob/master/exampleSite/content/_index.Rmarkdown) (which is not useful to you as an end-user of the theme). Open this file in your website project, and delete the bash code chunk. Then you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Its a windows issue (win7) with this particular theme.  running new_site() with the default theme works fine.