# Error serving Xmin Theme

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

Windows  10.

I built a site following the directions in the blogdown book, and then
tried switching to the author's Theme   Xmin it blew up.

Tried the fix the  author suggested here

[blogdown::new_site() bash not found on win7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232574/blogdownnew-site-bash-not-found-on-win7)

Also blew up.

panic: Too many homes

Has anybody had luck with this on windows? or is there an actual version that will work?

Comment: You mean you deleted https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin/blob/11ad2599ed983b8749fb2ce7f0a19f998c2998dd/exampleSite/content/_index.Rmarkdown#L13-L16? Please report your hugo version `blogdown::hugo_version()` and `sessionInfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue on Windows 7. Please consider upgrading Hugo and retry:

```
blogdown::update_hugo()
blogdown::new_site(theme = 'yihui/hugo-xmin')
```